# Unable to select Bluetoooth boom box

Tags: audio

I managed to idetify Bluetooth speaker. 
I have "paired" it, as far as Bluetooth is concerned it is connected ,  to the Pi 3B and was directed to "audio menu" to actaully select the speaker as audio output. 
Found under "preferences" item "audio device setting" but 
there is only **one audio resource available** , hence I cannot select the Bluetooth speaker box.

Running current, and upgraded OS.

Please answer the following questions:

1. Is this the correct menu to select audio output device ?

if so, see 2. ,  and if not , where is the correct menu?

2. Why is the Bluetooth speaker missing from selection AKA did I missed a step

Comment: Normaly, you should do bluetoothctl, and then you should pair, trust, and connect the device. Did you do the connect and trust part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***** Answer 1. It is not.
Right click on "Volume control" (!) lets you select the audio device. 
Volume control != audio MENU selection ****** 
Answer 2.  "audio device setting" menu window /control is ONLY for internal audio hardware , not for Bluetooth